# Waiting for Crashlytics - in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

I've installed Crashlytics on my eclipse.

http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse/

It's installed and I've added my project and tested. It's worked well.

Today when I open my eclipse, the Crashlytics icon is like disabled. When I move the cursor to the icon, it's showing "Waiting for Crashlytics..."

I've restarted my eclipse but not use. The same message showing.

I've uninstalled the Crashlytics and install newly. After restart the eclipse still it's showing "Waiting for Crashlytics..."

[image]

-

Is anyone facing this?

What is the issue? How to resolve this?

Comment: I'm facing this issue now and your solution unfortunately isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have pushed an update two days ago, try to uninstall the plugin manually and install it again.

Comment: i've uninstall the from eclipse and install new . but still the same message showing.